# How to make picture box background transparent in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

Suppose i have a big Picture box that its image is like a grid.. and 5 other small picture boxes that have different images that i want to place them in the big one and their location is always changeable(by changing their location randomly and sometimes they rotate ).
However , the problem is that these picture boxes have the background white and not transparent everytime i compiled my code as i changed their property back color to transparent
i tried this general code (that i found it alot as a solution for my problem):

```
overImage.Parent = backImage;
overImage.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
overImage.Location = thePointRelativeToTheBackImage;
```

and tried this:

```
innerPictureBox.SendToBack();
innerPictureBox.Parent = outerPictureBox;
```

but they work so badd and they only work for one time...what to do if i want to make them always transparent with not changing their desired location where i want to put them

Comment: You can't.  Winforms doesn't really do transparency. If you want in Winforms to overlap transparent images, you'll have to composite them yourself in a single control. If it's practical for you to switch to WPF for this one feature, you can do this in that API.

Comment: thanks man.. it worked but in a strange way..i screenshotted the scrren ...then cropped it and putted it as a background image so can the transparency work from the form's background lol